# Java remembering reference

Tags: java, methods, reference

I am creating object via method. Then I want to "destroy" it. I need to somehow remember a reference to specified object to call `destroy()` on it? How do I do it?

```
public class Obj {
     private int size;
     private boolean exist;

     private Obj(int size) {
          this.size = size;
          this.exist = true;
     }

     public static Obj getObj(int size) {
          Obj s = new Obj(size);
          return s;
     }

     public void destroy() {
          exist = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: The class that calls `getObj(int)` is the one that should be responsible to call `destroy()` on it (presumably when it's done using it). That doesn't look like something you have to do in this `Obj` class.

Comment: for java, as long as there are no objects are using (refer) to this object, it will be cleared automatically. Refer to the GC guides for details. Is there any specific reason you want to destroy it manually?

Comment: What is the purpose of  `public static Obj getObj(int size)` which does what a public constructor could do ?

Answer (score 1):

So, your method creates an resource, some other entity operates on it and then you release the resource. Am I warm?

In that case, the clean approach is to pass the code that operates on the object through as a function object, so you can definitely clean up as it exits. The general idea is called Execute Around.

```
 import java.util.function.Consumer;

 public static void getObj(int size, Consumer<Obj> consumer) {
      Obj s = new Obj(size);
      try {
          consumer.accept(s);
      } finally {
          s.destroy();
      }
 }
```

Use as:

```
Obj.getObj(1066, s -> {
    ... something with s ...;
});
```

Alternatively there is `java.lang.AutoCloseable` and try-with-resource which places responsibility on the caller so is best avoided if possible.

In any case, attempting to pool mutables in a static is generally a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remember a reference of a variable with in a class, you can declare it in class level and use it in initialise and destroy methods

```
class Obj {
   private static Obj s; 
   public static int getObj(){
        s=new Obj();
   }
   public void destroy (){
        s=null;
   }
}
```

Comment: this will null only the lust object created

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector should do it for you... however if you want to call destroy implicitly, you can define a class level list of all instances

```
public class Obj {
     private int size;
     private boolean exist;
     private static List<Obj> list = new ArrayList<>();


     private Obj(int size) {
          this.size = size;
          this.exist = true;
     }

     public static Obj getObj(int size) {
          Obj s = new Obj(size);
          list.add(s) // save ref
          return s;

     }

     public void destroy() {
          exist = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: In this case you want `destroy` null all list objects.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to be trying to educate you about garbage collection.

But to answer your actual question... In your code, you will need to call the factory method and assign the result to a variable: `Obj obj = Obj.getObj(1234)`. This is your reference to the object. When you want to call the `destroy()` method you use that reference.

For example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Obj obj = Obj.getObj(42);
        obj.destroy();
    }
}
```